# In Android5.0 when the current user is secondary user , how to make sure the app does not run

Tags: android

In android5.0, when the current user is secondary user,
how to make sure the app can not run ?

I installed the app when the user is primary user, and when I changed the user to a secondary user, I do not want the app to run. Is there any way to do that ?

By the way, I do not use the profile, just the app's behavior.

Comment: Is your objective to make sure that your app gets purchased more than once should more than one user use it?  Or is your objective to make sure that if the primary user uses a porn app, that the secondary user doesn't see it? If it's the latter case, I think you should avoid duplicating the "restricted profile" functionality that Google provides. Restricted profiles already work perfectly well for things like porn, or financial apps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But my app is not porn or financial app that can use restricted profile to control. My app is a bussiness app that need control in the app that can not run by the secondary user. I need some source add into the my app that can do this in the app itself.